# Install Ubuntu and Windows on the same pc

Tags: 14.04, windows-7

Some time ago I installed windows and ubuntu on the same pc. There was a problem and in grub boot loader, windows didn't appear, and I needed to reinstall all.

Now I want to install windows and ubuntu on other pc, but i can't remember... do I need to install windows or ubuntu firstly?

Thank you!

Comment: Just so you know, there are simple tools for recovering your Windows boot record in case anything goes wrong. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(a) For a dual boot machine, it is recommended that you install Windows first, with sufficient space for a blank partition, where Ubuntu would be installed.

(b) In case you wish to have a Ubuntu based machine, install Ubuntu first, and then install Virtualbox. Inside virtualbox, install your legal copy of Windows.